# pandas / numpy reduce time for na checks (is_valid_na_for_dtype / is_na)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

Hello I have a small project that I iterate over a dataframe and do stuff with this data..
I know that if I can I should avoid iterate the rows but I'm afraid that I must so I use itertuples.

Now I want to make my program run even faster so I optimize every bottleneck that I found and now I'm stuck with this:
Profiling my program show that 1/3 of the run time is for na checks:
[image]

Is there a way to tell pandas to consider that my dataframe is without na values and maybe run faster?

### UPDATE

I tried to override this method like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
def f(*args):
    return False
pd.core.dtypes.missing.is_valid_na_for_dtype = f
```

but it's not really override it, and the original method is get called

Comment: Filter the na first?

Comment: @jhylands Thank you for the reply, If I wasn't clear I dont have na values so that my question because its redundant check for me.